# pass multiple tag values to ec2.describe_instances

Tags: python, boto3

I am trying to write a boto3 python code that will accept multiple tag values on the command line and pass that to the ec2_describe instances for filtering out instances based on tags. I was able to write with python argparse which accepts multiple tag values. I took the arguments and converted them to string as below,

```
{'Name':'tag:Name','Values':['test-server']},{'Name':'tag:Age','Values':['30']}
```

But when I pass the above string to filters as
filters =[tag_string]

It throws an error that it expects a Dict rather than a string. Struggling with how to handle this code.

Comment: Can you share the code where you create the tag-string?

Comment: Thanks Bert, this was my first Question so how can i add the code here ?

Comment: You should be able to edit your question to add code. See this Q on how to format it appropriately: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Syntax definition needs to be updated to filter the EC2 instances based on tags.

the syntax is `{'Name': f'tag:{tag_key_name}', 'Values': [tag_value]}`

```
from boto3 import client

ec2 = client("ec2")
ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': f'tag:{tag_key_name}', 'Values': [tag_value]}])
```

Example:

In your case, it is:

```
ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': f'tag:{"Name"}', 'Values': ['test-server']}])
```

More information on describe ec2 instance can be found in the documentation of [Boto3 Describe the EC2 instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances)